# Displaying whole page nav shade

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, nav

I'm designing a navigation shade for a personal project that'll look the same on all devices vs the hamburger solely on mobile. At the moment I'm using `☰` and `×` for the navigation but would like to eventually animate these and the shade opening but I need it to be functional first.

My issue at the moment though is allowing the navigation shade to display on top of the site and be closed using the `×`. An issue with a lot of mobile sites is that you can't tap elsewhere below the drop-down menu and this alleviates the user issue of trying to close it a different way.

Here's the code I'm using;

```css
.site-header {
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 display: inline-flex;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 10px #000000;
}

.site-header-fill {
 height: 80px;
}

.site-logo-container {
 height: 60px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.site-logo {
 height: 60px;
 width: auto;
 float: left;
}

.site-nav-action-container {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 max-width: 50px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 display: block;
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
}

.site-nav {
 height: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #3399ff;
 z-index: 2;
}

.site-nav-content {
 width: 20%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .site-nav-content {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
}

.site-nav-pages {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-header ">
   <div class="site-logo-container">
      <img class="site-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" alt="Logo">
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav" onclick="location.href='/'">
         <p class="site-log-in-text w700">☰</p>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="site-nav">
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav" onclick="location.href='/'">
         <p class="site-log-in-text w700">X</p>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-content">
      <div class="site-nav-pages">
         <p>Page 1</p>
         <p>Page 2</p>
         <p>Page 3</p>
         <p>Page 4</p>
         <p>Page 5</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem you'll see when you run it is that the navigation shade is always present. I'm not sure which approach to take for showing it/having it hidden initially.

Ideally pressing the  `☰` should open it and the `×` close it. It's fine for it to display over the top of the page content because it'll always fill the whole screen. I'm just not sure which approach to take.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `<button class="nav">` elements to switch between states. A state can be defined in CSS, like how does it look by default and how does it look when activated. In your case you'll want to change the state of the `<div class="site-nav">` element to hide by default, and show when clicking the button.

Remove the `onclick` attributes on the buttons as you don't want to navigate. Instead select them in JavaScript and listen for the click. Give them both the same event handler function that will toggle a class on the `site-nav` element.

In your CSS add `opacity: 0` and `visibility: hidden` to the `.site-nav` styles. This will make the element transparent and hide it completely. These properties also allow you to use a transition from visible to invisible and vice versa.

```js
const navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.nav');
const siteNav = document.querySelector('.site-nav');

function onClick(event) {
  siteNav.classList.toggle('active');
}

navButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', onClick));
```

```css
.site-header {
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 display: inline-flex;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 10px #000000;
}

.site-header-fill {
 height: 80px;
}

.site-logo-container {
 height: 60px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.site-logo {
 height: 60px;
 width: auto;
 float: left;
}

.site-nav-action-container {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 max-width: 50px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 display: block;
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
}

.site-nav {
 height: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #3399ff;
 z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out, visibility 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.site-nav.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.site-nav-content {
 width: 20%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .site-nav-content {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
}

.site-nav-pages {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-header ">
   <div class="site-logo-container">
      <img class="site-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" alt="Logo">
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav">
         <p class="site-log-in-text w700">☰</p>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="site-nav">
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav">
         <p class="site-log-in-text w700">X</p>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-content">
      <div class="site-nav-pages">
         <p>Page 1</p>
         <p>Page 2</p>
         <p>Page 3</p>
         <p>Page 4</p>
         <p>Page 5</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works in the snippet but not when it's on my site in a script tag. Any ideas why this may be? I appreciate the slight animation added. I'm debating having one button that's always on top as a toggle that way it can animate between `☰` and  `×`

Comment: The script which controls the click of the buttons should come **after** the buttons in the HTML. Generally it's a good practice to place the `<script>` tags before the ending `</body>` tag after all the other HTML elements that you use in the script. Otherwise the HTML elements would not yet exist when the script is executed.

Comment: I'd missed a few tags and my CSS was cached so didn't immediately update - thanks for your help.